# Send and get information for Restfull and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am beginner with spring - boot and webservice, I have two exercises to do, they would know How to implement the client and the run () method; to send and receive strings trough In this webservice?

**PROJECT CONSUMER**

```
public class Service implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Send the messages....");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Service());
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // Loop receiving messages
    }
}
```

**PROJECT PRODUCER**

```
@Path("/greet")
@Component
public class GreetResource {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetResource.class);

    @Autowired
    Client client;

    public GreetResource() {
        logger.info("Resource Initialized");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{msg}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE })
    public Response echo(@PathParam("msg") String message) {
        return Response.ok().entity(message).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/send")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE })
    public boolean sendMessage(String greeting) {

        client.sendAMessage(greeting);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**PROJECT PRODUCER**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() throws IOException {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            logger.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
        } else {
            logger.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
            Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
            if (activeProfiles.contains("dev") && activeProfiles.contains("prod")) {
                logger.error("You have misconfigured your application! "
                        + "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("weather application service starting...");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**PROJECT PRODUCER**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Client  {

    public boolean sendAMessage(String greeting) {
        // Send the message

    return false;
    }
}
```

Any tips to implement method `run ()` and `sendAMessage()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot and want to implement web-service , then easiest way is to implement web service using RESTapi.

You can use `@ResponseBody` or `@RestController` annotations to expose service.

Comment: as would the implementation of the run and sendAmessage methods?

I googled but I understood not to apply to my case


the goal is just to send and receive a String